# Replacing a word with sed except when preceded by comments

Tags: linux, sed

I am trying to a figure out a way to replace a word on every instance of a line except when it is commented. For example replace `foo` with `bar`

INPUT:

```
I want to replace this foo ! but not this foo
! I don't want to replace this foo
I want to replace this foo and this foo as well
```

OUTPUT:

```
I want to replace this bar ! but not this foo
! I don't want to replace this foo
I want to replace this bar and this bar as well
```

Comment: This looks like homework, and this is not a free homework website. Just posting questions without showing that you have made any effort solving your problem does not impress most Stackexchange contributors. Thus the downvote.

Comment: Having said that, your example seems to imply that `foo` is surrounded by spaces. Is that so, or do you have to replace any `foo`, e.g. in the word `blafoobar`? And is `sed` a requirement?

Comment: If `awk` is allowed, use the comment sign as the field delimiter and use `gsub()` to replace `foo` in the first field of each line. This works whether `foo` is part of a word or not.

Comment: This is not a homework question, this is a work question as I am new to linux so I really appreciate the downvote. I was asking about sed specifically because I didn't know any other way this could be handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you tagged your question `sed`, here's one approach using it:

- if a line contains a comment, copy to hold space
- replace every instance of `foo` in the pattern space
- take everything up to the comment marker from the (modified) pattern space, and everything thereafter from the (original) hold space:

So

```
$ sed -e '/!/h' -e 's/foo/bar/g' -e '/!/{G;s/!.*!/!/}' file
I want to replace this bar ! but not this foo
! I don't want to replace this foo
I want to replace this bar and this bar as well
```

If you need to handle the case of `!` characters *within* a comment, ex.

```
$ cat file
I want to replace this foo ! but not!!! this foo
!! I don't want to replace this foo !!
I want to replace this foo and this foo as well
```

then you could do something like

```
$ sed -e '/!/{s//\n&/;h}' -e 's/foo/bar/g' -e '/!/{G;s/\n.*\n//}' file
I want to replace this bar ! but not!!! this foo
!! I don't want to replace this foo !!
I want to replace this bar and this bar as well
```